# Getting errors trying to mount a share with windows

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

I'm trying to mount a share from Windows on a new 20.04 installation.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=*********,password=********* smb://SKYHAWK/Pape/ Windows
```

Throws the following error

```
Mounting cifs URL not implemented yet. Attempt to mount smb://SKYHAWK/Pape/
```

using the path `SKYHAWK/Pape/` throws `mount.cifs: bad UNC (SKYHAWK/Pape/)`, and the path `//SKYHAWK/Pape` throws

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong.  Is my syntax wrong? Or does this method not work on 20.04?

Comment: Just remove the `smb:`.  Also, make sure that you are in the same folder as Windows folder is, or specify where it is like `/Windows` or `/media/Windows`.

Comment: I did as suggested, and it's throwing the permissions error.

Answer (score 0):

This method works just fine in 20.04 LTS.  My answer below is written from 20.04.

---

First off, the `smb:` before the rest of the server name is not needed.  When mounting a samba mount on another computer you need to make sure that the mount has the proper permissions on the server.  Check on the server the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file for the mount and the permissions.

Here is what my share looks like in my `smb.conf` file:

```
[storage]
   path = "/media/storage"
   directory mask = 0775
   create mask = 0775
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   admin users = terrance
```

Then to mount that share from the server to the local computer you use the following format of the command to mount it.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<username>,password=<password> //ServernameOrIP/sharename /path/to/local/mount
```

**Make sure that the username and password that you are using are the same credentials you use to access the samba server.**  The reason for ServernameOrIP is that sometimes you don't have the server name in DNS or specified in the `/etc/hosts` of the local system.

Here's an example of how I mount it on my system from my server:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=terrance,password=sambapassword //10.0.0.220/storage /cifs
```

Hope this helps!